# C++ How to overload an operator without an identifier before it

Tags: c++, math, operator-overloading, operators, identifier

For example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
int a;
+a;

}
```

I want the arithmetic plus " + " operator to be overloaded so that if it appears before one identifier ( in this case "a" ) , it will print " Hello ", without another identifer before the " + " operator , basically not like this :  "identifierA+identifierB " , but like this " +identifierB " ( in this case "+a") and the result of the program compilation to be " Hello ".
How is this possible?

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: The language does not allow overloading existing operators for fundamental types.

Comment: For example, I have a dynamic pointer and i'm accessing index 2:               " *(pointer+1)  " , I tried to figure out how there can be an operator such as asterisk before an identifier of some sort, without an identifier before that.

Comment: To overload the unary plus operator for a user defined type, refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117563/use-of-unary-plus-operator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, overloading existing operators for fundamental types is not allowed in C++. You may overload operators for user defined types, but that isn't your question.